# How to convert a comma separated string of numbers to an array of integers?

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have the string `1,2,3,4,5` and I want to convert this to an array of integers - what would be the best way?

I know I can use explode to create an array with the string but I need the array items to be integers.

Comment: "but I need the array items to be integers..." - why? Is it about validating the values?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to apply [`intval`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to each array item after you explode the string:

```
$string = "1,2,3,4,5";
$int_array = array_map("intval", explode(",", $string));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also type cast it.

```
$string = "1,2,3,4,5"; 
$explode = explode(',', $string);

foreach ($explode as $key)
$arrIntegers[] = (int) $key;


var_dump($arrIntegers);
```